# Python xml.parsers.expat results differ based on buffer_text = True or False and/or buffer_size

Tags: python, xml

I'm using Python's xml.parsers.expat to parse some xml data, but sometimes the tags doesn't seem to be parsed correctly. I wonder if anyone knows if  why setting buffer_text and / or buffer_size might actually change whether the data body gets parsed correctly?

A sanitized example, used to parse Azure blob list:

```
from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate, ExpatError, errors

class MyParser:
    def __init__(self, xmlstring):
        self.current_blob_name = None
        self.current_blob_hash = None
        self.get_hash = False
        self.get_filename = False
        self.xmlstring = xmlstring
        self.p = ParserCreate()
        #### LINE A ####
        self.p.buffer_text = True
        #### LINE B ####
        # self.p.buffer_size = 24
        self.p.StartElementHandler = self._start_element
        self.p.EndElementHandler = self._end_element
        self.p.CharacterDataHandler = self._char_data
    def _reset_current_blob(self):
        self.current_blob_name = None
        self.current_blob_hash = None
    # 3 handler functions
    def _start_element(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'Blob':
            self._reset_current_blob()
        elif name == 'Name':
            self.get_filename = True
        elif name == 'Content-MD5':
            self.get_hash = True
    def _end_element(self, name):
        if name == 'Blob':
            ...
        elif name == 'Name':
            self.get_filename = False
        elif name == 'Content-MD5':
            self.get_hash = False
    def _char_data(self, data):
        if self.get_hash is True:
            self.current_blob_hash = data
        if self.get_filename is True:
            try:
                ...
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error parsing blob name from Azure.')
                print(e)
    def run(self):
        self.p.Parse(self.xmlstring)
```

Most of the time things work just fine. However, sometimes after I upload a new item to Azure and that the xml returned changes, The error "Error parsing blob name from Azure" will get triggered, since some operations in the `try` block gets unexpected data. Upon further inspection, I observe that one potential error happens when `data` is supposed to be `abcdefg_123/hijk/test.jpg`, only `abcdefg` got passed into `_char_data`, while `_123/hijk/test.jpg` gets passed into another item. There is nothing wrong with the xml returned from Azure though.

I've experimented with a few things:

1. Added `LINE A` (buffer_text = True). It fixed the issue this time but I do not know if it is just luck (e.g. whether it would break again if I upload a new item to Azure);
2. If both `LINE A` and `LINE B` are added - things break again (I've also experimented with different buffer sizes; all seem to break the parser);
3. The way it breaks is deterministic: I can rerun the code all I want and it is always the exact element that gets parsed incorrectly;
4. If I remove that element from the original xml data, depending on how much other data I remove along the way, it could lead to another element being parsed incorrectly, or it could lead to a "fix" / no error. It **does** look like it has something to do with the **total length of the data** returned from Azure. My data is quite long (3537860 characters at this moment), and if I remove a fixed length from anywhere in the xml data, once the length reach a certain value, no more errors occur.

Unfortunately I am not able to share the raw xml I am parsing since it would take too much effort to sanitize, but hopefully this contains enough information! Let me know if I can add anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Walter:
https://bugs.python.org/msg385104

> Just a guess, but the buffer size might be so small that the text that you expect gets passed via **two** calls to _char_data(). You should refactor your code the simply collect all the text in _char_data() and act on it in the _end_element() handler.
> So this probably isn't a bug in xml.parsers.expat.

This fix is working for me so far. What I did not understand is that I thought the default buffer was 24, but if I set it to say 48 (a larger buffer), I would again see the issue (before this fix). In any case, collecting all data in the _char_data() section does make sense to me.